# Is it possible to affect a brain with electromagnetic waves?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

A human brain can generate electrical signal. So it generates magnetic field as well. Is it possible to affect a brain with electromagnetic waves?

Comment: Sorry... your post is incomprehensible in its current state.  What exactly are you trying to theorize can be done, and what do you mean by "mind connect with EM wave controlling device"?  Please clarify.

Comment: Yes.  As a trivial example, put the brain in a microwave oven and cook it :-)

Answer (score 2):

One can use [transcranial magnetic stimulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcranial_magnetic_stimulation) to modulate neural activity. This is effectively inducing a current in the tissue under a magnetic coil.